AWS lambda function skipping invocations
I have a lambda function scheduled to run every min using an eventbridge schedule.  This function sometimes takes longer than 1 min to run, however I was under the impression that AWS would simply invoke another instance of the function even if the first invocation is still running.  I have concurrency set to 1000.
Looking at the cloudwatch logs, my function starts, takes a little longer than a min to end, then is only invoked 1 min after the previous function has ended.  I want a new invocation every min, regardless if the previous function is finished or not.
One thing to note is that my true intention is to have the function run every 15 seconds, and I basically loop the code and have it sleep every 15 seconds at the end.  After 4 loops, it ends and ideally the next invocation should have started.  I'm not sure if me putting a sleep in is somehow delaying the next invocation.

@smac2020 are you sure? Can you point to supporting documentation? Why would a particular invocation's call to sleep() impact Eventbridge invoking a 2nd, concurrent execution at the next scheduled time? I can almost understand this if max (reserved) concurrency was set to 1 (which the OP did not mention) but even then I suspect the 2nd invocation would simply be delayed.

When you say "I have concurrency set to 1000", are you referring to Reserved Concurrency, Unreserved Account Concurrency or Provisioned Concurrency? The discussion on Can AWS Scheduled Lambda run again before finished? suggests that multiple executions of the scheduled Lambda function will run simultaneously.
